# Artifacts in Unity

Tags: 11.10, unity, visual-artifacts

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10. Sometimes I get strange artifacts on the screen, mainly in the Unity toolbar, but also in some applications such as Firefox.
I can't find a way to reproduce the problem, it seems to appear randomly.

I can continue working because the system is still usable, but it's a bit dissapointing.

I took a screenshot to clarify what's happening.

[image]
Can you help me with this? Thank you very much and sorry for my bad english.

PS: I'm using an ATI Radeon x1550 with the default drivers and Unity 3d

Answer (score 1):

I was getting something like that (gateway nv57) every now and again but then I upgraded my ram and eveything went away.